# How to play the youtube video without youtube logo in android

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, youtube, android-videoview

I am working on android > API 8 , the problem is I would like to play the youtube video without showing the youtube logo on either info bar, control bar or bottom right corner.

I tried using webview and the embedd link , it turnes out there is logo on it even using modestbranding. Then I tried using video view, it is actually with the logo but the problem is the the rtsp video is very low quality

How to fix the problem? Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong showing the youtube logo when you are using their service? Try making your own video site then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Android [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)!
The YouTube Android Player API enables you to incorporate video playback functionality into your Android applications. The API defines methods for loading and playing YouTube videos (and playlists) and for customizing and controlling the video playback experience.